# Authentication for mobile application

Tags: web-services, rest, api

I am new to web services and I am writing a functional specification document for a mobile app.

The mobile application user should be able to verify his login and password against my webservice to verify he has access to the app. (app is connected to sql azure DB backend). With which protocols do I acquire this?

Than the mobile app need to make new web service calls for this user. Every new call need to be verified that this user is logged in. How would you acquire this behaviour?

thank you already for your answers.
(other approaches may also be proposed)

Comment: usually that is something that a web framework of your choice handles for you. Do you have any framework in mind that you want to use for your proposal?

Comment: Have you tried creating a session using ajax call from your application. That should auth you and then use tokens or something similar to manage time based auth if you need. At least show us you have tried something.